# comparing a two lists and adding them to another

Tags: python, list, append

What I am trying to do is compare a huge list that have hundreds of different looking versions of this

```
['8956', '39', '0', '220', '138', '152', '0.28\n']
```

(we'll call this BigList). and i want it to compare to this

```
[47.0, 0.5, 219, 121, 220.763, 5]
```

(we can call this smallList). The four digit number can be ignored in the BigList because it's not important. When comparing, if three or more of the numbers from BigList are bigger than the smallList, I want to append it to a new list and vice versa.

My idea was to compare them in a for loop, but I dont know how to check to see if each individual number is bigger or smaller than what its being compared to.

Edit:For example: If we were to compare the two right now. I want to ignore the '8956' because its not important for comparing.Then we would start to compare like a parallel list. Since BigList has only two numbers that are bigger than the ones in smallList. We would put it into a separate list containing numbers smaller than smallList.

Comment: Both of list ie. big-list | small-list are of string or float type ? or big list of string and small of ints and float as you have written

Comment: means both of same type ? even after editing, it reflects string for biglist and int/floats for second

Comment: You need to show the expected result as I cannot tell what you are actually asking.

Comment: Also , are you looking to compare w.r.t index position of list elements like 8956 should be compared with 47.0 , 39 should be comapred with 0.5 and so on...?

Comment: @Tanu I want to ignore the 8956, but the rest should be compared like parallel list.  '47' compared to '39', '0.5' to '0', etc.

Comment: you can remove the numbers from the list you want to ignore and then compare the list parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can convert both lists to numerical data (it seems like bigList is a string), you can use [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html) to achieve what you want.

Example:

```
In [104]: import numpy as np
In [105]: bigList = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
In [106]: smallList = np.random.randint(10, size=10)

In [107]: bigList
Out[107]: array([5, 3, 2, 1, 9, 2, 1, 9, 4, 4])

In [108]: smallList
Out[108]: array([0, 7, 9, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3])

In [109]: np.greater(bigList, smallList)
Out[109]: array([ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [110]: np.greater(bigList, smallList).sum()
Out[110]: 5
```

Every time an element from `bigList` is greater than an element from `smallList` you will add `1` to the sum.

So to solve your problem, you can set a condition on `np.greater(bilgiest, smallList)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the number having digits greater than 4 from Biglist and append others to a new Biglist which can be used to compare from small list

```
 Updatedbiglist = []
 for big in Biglist:
     if len(str(big))<4:
         Updatedbiglist.append(big)
```

You can use python `zip` operator which merge two lists in pairs. Now it becomes easy to compare elements of lists

```
new_list = []
for big,small in zip(Updatedbiglist,Smalllist):
    if big > small:
        new_list.append(big)

print new_list
```

`new_list` will have elements which are bigger in biglist